# android-how to close cursor in a class like this

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have this function inside my dbhelper class :

```
public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null,null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }

    return c;
}
```

when I come to the activity where this class calls, I get this error (Please notice when I enter this activity I get this error not when leaving the activity ):

```
Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database......
Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
```

it's a very long error .

someone told me to use c.close(); above return c, something like this:

```
public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null,null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        c.close();
        return c;
    }
```

I tried it but now I get this error :

```
Access closed cursor
```

What should I do ? How should I close the cursor in this class?

Comment: Close the cursor after iterating.

Comment: You are returning a CLOSED CURSOR. REMOVE c.close();

Comment: You should close the cursor in the (cursor iterating) class that could be the main activity or something else.

Comment: @LavekushAgrawal thanks for the replies , if I understand you correcly you mean I close the cursor onStop() or onDestroy() , I'm doing this but this is not solving my problem ,When I come to activity I get this error , I'm still on the activity and I didn't leave it .

Comment: don't close cursor in onStop/Destroy, you should free cursor as soon as you are finished iterating over it.

Answer (score 2):

You should close the `Cursor` in your `Activity`. like

```
 Cursor c=getRow(rowID_Value);
 c.close();
```

After getting used of your `DB` you must close this `Cursor`.

Answer (score 1):

Close the cursor after using  `getRow` function,i.e.

```
public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null,null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }
```

and use it like this

```
Cursor c1 = getRow(rowId);
//use cursor 
//....
if(c1 != null)c1.close();
```

Note : rowId is the value of row which you want from database in long format.

**Edit**

Create `Cursor c1;` in your activity class.
check first if cursor is not null,then close it.

```
if(c1 != null)c1.close();
```

then get cursor as

```
 c1 = getRow(rowId);
```

And onStop/onDestroy close cursor as

```
if(c1 != null)c1.close();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , in the activity I close the cursor in onStop and onDestrory . The problem is this ,When I come to this activity it shows this error , I'm still on the activity and I get the erro not when I'm leaving the activity .

Comment: @user3718930 please post error exception in your question.

Comment: @user3718930 check cursor nullability,see edited answer.

Comment: @user3718930 close cursor after using it,as I suggested,why are you closing in onStop() function,for more please post logcat exception.

Comment: I can close the cursor but I use cursor further more , for example when I click on favorite button , it gets the id from cursor and lots of places that gets the data from cursor , If I close it , I don't have the values

Comment: @user3718930 then try to create "Cursor c1" as class variable and the n onStop/onDestroyed  use if(c1 != null)c1.close(); as I suggest.see edited answer.

Comment: I didn't get you exactly , I'm new to android . How do I create "Cursor c1" as class variable ? I've a cursor and I close it in onStop/onDestory but the problem is when I enter the activity

Answer (score 0):

hello i have face this same problem i have solve this problem like

when i am query and returning `ArrayList` or `JSON object` not `cursor`

may you need to change your query

```
public JSONObject getRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null,null, null);
   if (c!= null & c.moveToFirst()) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

         jsonObj.put("key_Name", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("your_column_name")));
         // do for your all column and return this jsonObj and before returning close cursor
    }
    c.close();
    return jsonObj;
}
```

this is for only returning one record for retuning set of record i am use this lib

> https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex

it will manage cursor operation itself and return us `sqliteCursorLoader`